# Borrowed and captured variable in RUST

Tags: reference, rust, paho

I am working with `paho_mqtt`, and I want to send messages on topics according to those received. I divided my code into nested functions, and I use the variable `cli` (cf code below). I think I need to use references to have a working code, but I still don't figure how. Thank you for your help.

*Code:*

```
fn publish_fail_msg(cli: mqtt::AsyncClient, topic: String){
        let msg = mqtt::Message::new(topic, "Fail", QOS[0]);
        cli.publish(msg);
}

fn manage_msgs(cli: mqtt::AsyncClient, msg: mqtt::Message){
        let topic = msg.topic();
        let payload_str = msg.payload_str();

        match topic {
                "main"  => publish_new_topic(cli, payload_str.to_string()),
                _       => publish_fail_msg(cli, topic.to_string()),
        }
}

fn main() -> mqtt::AsyncClient {
        // Create the client connection
        let mut cli = mqtt::AsyncClient::new(create_opts).unwrap_or_else(|e| {
                println!("Error creating the client: {:?}", e);
                process::exit(1);
        });

        // Attach a closure to the client to receive callback on incoming messages.
        cli.set_message_callback(|_cli, msg| {
                if let Some(msg) = msg {
                        manage_msgs(cli, msg);
                }
        });

        cli
}
```

*Error:*

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
   --> src/main.rs:230:25
    |
212 |     let mut cli = mqtt::AsyncClient::new(create_opts).unwrap_or_else(|e| {
    |         ------- captured outer variable
...
230 |             manage_msgs(cli, msg);
    |                         ^^^ cannot move out of captured variable in an `FnMut` closure

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `cli` because it is borrowed
   --> src/main.rs:228:30
    |
228 |     cli.set_message_callback(|_cli, msg| {
    |     --- -------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^ move out of `cli` occurs here
    |     |   |
    |     |   borrow later used by call
    |     borrow of `cli` occurs here
229 |         if let Some(msg) = msg {
230 |             manage_msgs(cli, msg);
    |                         --- move occurs due to use in closure

error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `cli`
   --> src/main.rs:248:5
    |
212 |     let mut cli = mqtt::AsyncClient::new(create_opts).unwrap_or_else(|e| {
    |         ------- move occurs because `cli` has type `mqtt::AsyncClient`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
228 |     cli.set_message_callback(|_cli, msg| {
    |                              ----------- value moved into closure here
229 |         if let Some(msg) = msg {
230 |             manage_msgs(cli, msg);
    |                         --- variable moved due to use in closure
...
248 |     cli.connect_with_callbacks(conn_opts, on_connect_success, on_connect_failure);
    |     ^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Answer (score 0):

The devil is in the details: I found the *issue*, which is the `_cli`. I replaced it with `cli: &mqtt::AsyncClient` and I could send the reference to my nested functions. Maybe there are better solutions for this, and it would be a pleasure to see them.